# Powershell 2: Optimal way to compute checksum on file?

Tags: powershell

I run a script to process a CSV file once an hour. At the beginning of the script, I need
to exit out if the CSV file has not changed. Let's pretend that file timestamps aren't an option. (I'm asking this question for educational value)

I was considering slurping in the entire file and computing the hash on the contents, like so:

```
$fileData = get-content \path\to\file
$hashCode = $fileData.GetHashCode()
```

I would then save those contents from run to run, and if the hash is the same on subsequent runs, exit out of my script.

Is there a better way to do this, again, assuming file timestamps are not available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll end up using the System.Security.Cryptography namespace to generate that hash.  The [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) have already done the work for you.  There is a Get-Hash cmdlet that returns a HashInfo object you could use for your comparison.

Comment: That is awesome - thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to note, the `Get-HashCode()` is not meant to be used as a unique object identifier. It will always be different every time you run it, even in the same session.

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Awesome - I had no idea. That is valuable info - thanks!